# Get entry with data field that is greater than specific entry

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table with entry `somefield`,`age` and `name`, where `name` entries are unique. I want to get all entries where age is greater than Tom's. How do I do this WITHOUT specifying Tom's age?
I am looking for something like

```
SELECT somefield WHERE age>tom.age
```

I am not allowed to select `age` specifically either, so something like this isn't allowed:

```
SELECT somefield WHERE age>(SELECT age WHERE name=TOM)
```

Last note: I am only allowed to select `somefield` in the sql statement which isn't relevant.

Comment: how about this? select a.somefield from table a
inner join table tom on tom.id=a.id
where a.age > tom.age

Answer (score 1):

Try using a join like this:

```
select p.somefield from people p
join people p1 on p1.name = 'Tom' and p.age > p1.age;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4PivMX85ZhU9UG6KcprT4P/0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT somefield
FROM t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM t2
              WHERE t2.name = 'TOM' and
                    t2.age < t.age
             );
```

You don't need to "select" anything -- just do the comparison in the `where` clause.